# Hide the navbar in a specific component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So I want to hide the navbar while in a mobile view state. The navbar was created on a seperate component. Here is my `admin.component.html` like here:

```
<div *ngIf="!isMobile">
  <div class="admin-container">
    <!-- sidebar -->
    <nav class="col-2 d-md-block sidebar collapse">
      <div class="sidebar-sticky pt-3">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/admin/dashboard"> Dashboard </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/admin/orders"> Orders </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/admin/adminProduct"> Products </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/admin/reports"> Reports </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- content -->
    <div class="admin-content p-3">
      <div
        class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center pb-2 mb-2 border-bottom"
      >
        <form novalidate #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="logout()">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-juliet mt-3">Logout</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="isMobile">
  <div class="admin-container">
    <!-- sidebar -->
    <nav class="col-2 d-md-block sidebar collapse">
      <div class="sidebar-sticky pt-3">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/admin/dashboard"> Dashboard </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/admin/orders"> Orders </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/admin/adminProduct"> Products </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/admin/reports"> Reports </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- content -->
    <div class="admin-content p-3">
      <div
        class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center pb-2 mb-2 border-bottom"
      >
        <form novalidate #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="logout()">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-juliet mt-3">Logout</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the `admin.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NavbarService } from '../services/navbar.service';
import { RibbonService } from '../services/ribbon.service';
import { ResponsiveService } from 'src/app/services/responsive.service';

import { FooterService } from '../services/footer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css'],
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  public isMobile: boolean;
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    public nav: NavbarService,
    public ribbon: RibbonService,
    public footer: FooterService,
    private router: Router,
    private responsive: ResponsiveService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.nav.hide();
    this.ribbon.hide();
    this.footer.hide();
    this.onResize();
    this.responsive.checkWidth();
  }

  
  logout() {
    this.authService.clear();
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
  }

  onResize() {
    this.responsive.getMobileStatus().subscribe((isMobile) => {
      this.isMobile = isMobile;
      this.nav.hide();
    });
  }

}
```

And my `app.component.html`

```
<app-ribbon></app-ribbon>
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="app-body" (window:resize)="onResize()">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

I tried applying `*ngIf` on the `admin.component.html` but the navbar won't go away. Thanks for the future answers!

Comment: Your `onResize()` method is in your admin.component.ts but you are calling it from app.component.html. That can't be correct. Also which element are you trying to hide, `app-navbar`?

Comment: oh my bad, it is also included in `app.component.ts`, I just did not put it. 

Yes, I'm trying to hide `app-navbar` in `admin.component.ts`

Comment: I don't see a `app-navbar` in the `admin.component.html`

Comment: Yeah, I tried deleting it earlier, still the navbar was there when it was on mobile view